# Database design for multiple game variations

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Hopefully the purpose of these tables will be apparent, but just in case here's a simple explanation: I basically wish to store the results of matches (8 ball pool etc.) but also log the results on a frame by frame basis. Where I am getting a problem is that I intend to allow for different game types as my application grows, and as such, the scoring system used within each frame would vary. I think the solution below could work, but it doesn't quite seem right to me, all advice is appreciated.

Is there a more sensible approach than using the following tables:

### # Players

- id
- name
- nickname

### # NormalMatches

- id
- playerA
- playerB

### # NormalFrames

- id
- match_id
- playerAWon (BOOL)

### # ScoringPoolMatches

- id
- playerA
- playerB

### # ScoringPoolFrames

- id
- match_id
- playerA_cue_ball_potted
- playerB_cue_ball_potted
- playerA_balls_potted
- playerB_balls_potted
- playerA_balls_remaining
- playerB_balls_remaining

(edit: altered ScoringPoolFrame table to give better idea of what the problem is.)

Many thanks.

Comment: You are right. Something is indeed missing. At the very least there is no mechanism to record where the score came from (what variant) and/or to otherwise differentiate it. I suspect some form of "Game" entity is missing.

Comment: I'd calculate the result of the match based on the frame results. In a normal match, only the winner of the frame is important so I'd loop through and see who had won the most (I use a Boolean here to save space - true if playerA wins, false otherwise).

The problem is that for a scoring match, each player might have different points. i.e. playerA might get 10 points in a frame and playerB might get 20 pts. There's a clear difference in how I'd then have to calculate the winner of the match.

Comment: Think about the model and the model stores stuff -- That's it :) For example, consider these questions: How is data put in? Does the model accurately represent the data put in? Does the data in the model contain all the information needed during later queries? Does the model contain *derived* information which can be removed? (E.g. is the model well-normalized?)

Comment: @pst In that case, is it not better to separate each of the entities as I have done? The approach I've shown inherently allows for future variations to be added. I just thought that the queries could become quite large (as trying to get all of the games that a player has played would need to query multiple tables). The flip side of that is that were I to query just a single game type, surely the query would be much quicker were the data separated into the various match types?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what the different is between your normal matches table and your scoring pool matches....
i would have things set up a little differently, with one table to score final win/loss results for a match, and one table to score all games/frames.  (* indicates a primary key field)

## Players

- id *
- name
- nickname

## Matches

- id *
- playerA
- playerB
- winning_player_id

## Games

- match_id *
- game_id *
- player_id
- score

the game_id would be a frame number in bowling, or a set number in tennis, or an inning in baseball

you might even want to flatten the matches table into something like this:

## Matches

- match_id *
- player_id *
- winner (bool)

so that you can select all matches for a certain player without searching on two columns.  you could also have more than two players in a game that way.

Comment: I'm sorry perhaps I wasn't as clear as I could have been. The difference between the scoring game and the normal games is that in a normal game there can be a winner and a loser, that is all. In the scoring game, both players have a score value which needs to be logged so the values can be totalled at the end of the game to give the result. These are basic examples, though, and more complex examples such as golf pool (see above) may be added at a later date.

Comment: Ok.  i think what i suggested still fits your needs.  For the "normal games" you would just have an entry in the Matches table (either version) and no entries in the games table.  like i mentioned, any match - the entire competition - can be broken down into games - periods, quarters, frames, etc.  the nomenclature can be changed around but the principle is the same.  you can add another column to the the games table that references another "scoreType" table to add detail to the score row.  "CueBallsPotted", "BallsPotted", "BallsRemaining" could all be entries in the "scoreType" table

Answer (score 0):

Guiding principle: Less is more. In this case, less tables = good.

A match is a match and a frame is a frame, so...

- Merge "NormalMatches" and "ScoringPoolMatches" tables together and introduce a column `is_scoring boolean` to differentiate
- Merge the "NormalFrames" and "ScoringPoolFrames" tables into simply "Frames" (id, playerA_score, playerB_score), but simply allocate a score of "1" for a win and "0" for a loss for normal games. Then your calculation of win/lose is the same for all frames.

Create view(s) to capture the logic of calculations, eg

```
CREATE VIEW FRAME_RESULT AS
SELECT
    id,
    playerA_score > playerB_score as playerAWon,
    playerB_score > playerA_score as playerBWon,
    playerA_score = playerB_score as is_draw
FROM Frames
```

Comment: Thanks this sounds promising. But what if I then add functionality for golf pool? Where each frame (hole) would have a par value and a setup? I've provided two examples for my example but there will likely be more than two game variations as it grows, predicting what these variations are is impossible at this point, so it would have to be as flexible as possible.